# python mock patch error

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I have multiple unit_test files created in my project.
When i run all the test files independtely, all files passes all the test cases.

But when i run all the test through TestRunner, i get error as

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
```

I have noticed that this error is thrown because of patching.

```
======================================================================
ERROR [0.001s]: test_create_pull_requests (test_custom_logs_manager.TestCustomLogManager)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/x/local/dmali/githome/am-repo/unit_tests/lib/mock/mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/x/local/dmali/githome/am-repo/unit_tests/data_process/caldata/test_custom_logs_manager.py", line 71, in test_create_pull_requests
    cal_handlers)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

...
```

Code Snippet:

```
@patch('data_process.caldata.custom_logs_manager.CustomLogsPullTrack',
       MagicMock(return_value = MockCustomLogsPullTrack()))
def test_create_pull_requests(self):
    """
    Unit Test for create_pull_requests
    """
    report_times = [datetime.datetime.now()]
    group_id = 1
    data_center = MockDataCenterCalLoc()
    data_center_cal_loc_id = 1
    mock_pull_config = MockPayMonCalBizConfig()
    mock_pull_config.id = 1
    cal_handlers = {'TEST_CAL': 'TEST_CLASS'}
    result = custom_logs_manager.create_pull_requests(report_times,
                                                      group_id,
                                                      data_center,
                                                      data_center_cal_loc_id,
                                                      mock_pull_config,
                                                      cal_handlers)

    self.assertEqual(result[0].paymon_calbiz_config_id, 1)
    self.assertEqual(result[0].pool_name, 'TEST')
    self.assertEqual(result[0].data_center_cal_loc_id, 1)
```

---

Comment: It looks like you're setting up your mocks incorrectly. I can't really be sure though without looking through your entire source code. I'm kind of unclear about why you're mocking a class, but then calling a function and expecting it to be mocked. Maybe look at your code a little more closely and spend some time debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the similiar problem in our unit testing framework. If the method that you are testing through unit test has the decorator "transaction.commit_manually", you need to have the same decorator in the unit test method. Otherwise you get this excpetion "None type object is not callable" which will give no clue about the actual issue.